# TeamCity - Create new text file only gets content of parameter name

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10

Using TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.2 (build 42234) I create a build step that looks like this:

- Runner type: Create Text File
- Step name: Adding password configuration
- Execute step: If all previous steps finished successfully
- File content: %password.config%
- Destination file:
  %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Project.Web\password.config

In Parameters I have a variable called "password.config".

- Name: password.config
- Kind: Configuration parameter
- %secure:teamcity.password.password.config% (I have added my values here)
- Spec: password display='hidden'

I have done this many times before, both with passwords that are hidden and plain text files. However this time the file gets created as normal but the value added is the following: `%password.config%`. It does not pick up the value from the parameter like the other files. This has happened once before but then it started working when I ran a new build the day after. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Where can I find `Runner type: Create Text File`? I do not see it...

Comment: @Serg046 Late answer, but they are here https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that the value contained percent signs `%` that were not escaped with `%%`. After escaping with two percentage signs everything worked. Probably cached value because the changes did not take effect right away.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration